# How do you follow a symbolic link under a root?

Tags: unison

I am syncing two machines using Unison:

```
root = /home/luserface
root =  ssh://192.168.1.168/
```

I have a subdirectory "Foo" under that home, and it's a symbolic link. I have

```
follow = Path Foo
```

in my Unison profile, but that does not work; that Path doesn't reference Foo. What is the path I want here?

Comment: As long as `Foo` is located at `/home/luserface/Foo` like you say, I think this *should* work. Try replacing `Path` with `Name`.

Comment: Name and Regexp don't work, either.

Comment: `Name` did the trick here

Comment: TEST:

1013  mkdir TT
1014  touch TT/foo
1016  ln -s TT TL

follow = Name TL

RESULTS:

unison copies the other Paths there,
but the output does not even mention "TL",
and neither the link nor the target are copied.